# Get date in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I think I have a stupid question again :-)

```
<%@language="JScript"%>
<%
htmlStr+="<tr><td><br/>Order date: "</td><tr>";
%>
```

How can I get and fill the actual date after Order date?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so JScript on the server side?

```
<%@language="JScript"%>
<%
var htmlStr = "", d = new Date();
htmlStr += "<tr><td><br/>Order date: " + d.getDate() + "</td><tr>";
Response.Write(htmlStr);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
document.write(d.getDate());
```